# JavaScript: How do I get arrow keys binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found some solutions like :

```
function checkKey(e) {

        e = e || window.event;

        if (e.keyCode == '38') {
            snakeDirection = "up";
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
            snakeDirection = "down";
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
           snakeDirection = "left";
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
           snakeDirection = "right";
        }
    }
```

But I don't know the meaning of this `e` nor `e = e || window.event;`
Can someone please explain?

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw I basically didn't copy the code .. but i did implement it in my code (a game). but thanks. :)

Comment: `document.onkeydown=checkKey`

Answer (score 0):

The function `checkKey` was meant to be used as an event listener, almost certainly for the `keydown` event. Try running this and you'll see what I mean:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey)
```

Event listeners in most modern browsers take a single parameter, the event object, which is often designated `e` (short for `event`).

However, in certain older browsers (namely legacy Internet Explorer versions) the event object was not passed to the listener; instead, one would access it using the global `window.event` property. If you wanted your code to be flexible for these browers, you would have to anticipate that `e` might not be passed. That is why the line `e = e || window.event` exists: it essentially says "If you can't find the variable `e`, set it to `window.event` and carry on."

This event object carries properties that help explain the specifics of the event that occured. For example, the property `keyCode` on the `keydown` event object tells you which key was pressed on the keyboard. However, these key codes are numbered in ways that are not easy to remember, hence the strange appearance of the `if` statements you are using:

- Left arrow corresponds to key code `37`
- Up arrow corresponds to key code `38`
- Right arrow corresponds to key code `39`
- Down arrow corresponds to key code `40`